# Securing Firebase CRUD operations with users

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

Due to the thin AngularFire documentation and the differences between it and the default web documentation for Firebase, I'm a little lost on how best to secure Create, Read, Update, and Delete operations with users.

In short, say I have an application that manages stores. Users can be owners of the stores or patrons. Owners should read and edit their own stores in their view and patrons should read all but edit no stores in their view.

I'm concerned about the security of suggested methods by Firebase docs such as

> So for example, we could have a rule like the following to allow users
>   to create comments as long as they store their user id with the
>   comment:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "$comment": {
      ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.child('user_id').val() == auth.id"
    }
  }
}
```

To me, this means that I could hack my application's data by simply passing in my victim's user id when I want to post a comment as them. Am I wrong?

I've read the security documentation thoroughly, several times. I think I need further explanation here. Identifying by a client-exposed parameter is the only method I can find so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example shown here, `auth` refers to the authenticated user's token data. This is a special variable set by Firebase during auth() events, and thus not something you could hack at the client. In other words, you would only be able to write a comment if you set the user_id value to your own account id.

The contents of the `auth` object depend on how the client authenticates. For example, SimpleLogin's [password](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html) provider puts the following into the auth token: `provider`, `email`, and `id`; any of which could be utilized in the security rules.

It's also possible to [sign your own tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html) from a server, and of course the sky is the limit here.

But the bottom line is that the token's internal values are provided by a trusted process and not by the client, and thus cannot be altered by a user.

Comment: Oh, well that's good news. So I could match these super long auth strings in the auth object to properties of the data in question.

Comment: But aren't some of those tokens subject to change, due to expiration and such? I'm worried that if I connect data to such a token, that they'll be locked out of their data suddenly once the token changes.

Comment: If anyone from Firebase is listening, I recommend integrating something like what Kinvey has, where each collection can have one of four generic access templates or it can optionally fall back to business logic, like Firebase's rules.

Comment: I don't think you understand--the auth data is tied to its associated account (i.e. combination of username and password). It doesn't expire. And what you match is not the token itself, but data contained in the secure auth variable (i.e. email or id).

Comment: I see, thank you @bennlich. You are correct. Although it is certainly not secure that I can access someone's data by simply finding their facebook ID, which is publicly available.

Comment: Still not quite right =P. A user cannot modify his/her auth variable willy-nilly. The auth variable is created securely from the token provided during authentication (scroll down to the [After Authenticating](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html) section) and cannot be modified by the client. In other words, one does not simply walk into mordor. The Firebase crew is much smarter than that...